# Cannot find ArrayList type in System.Collections

Tags: c#, arraylist

I wrote this code `private ArrayList articles = new ArrayList();` and it just won't compile.
Visual Studio is giving me this error:

> The type or namespace name 'ArrayList' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Yet i made sure to import the System.Collections Namespace.
I even tried with

```
System.Collections.ArrayList articles = new ArrayList();
```

But no success either. Thanks for any help

Comment: System.Collections.ArrayList articles = new System.Collections.ArrayList();
would be the correct Syntax there. However it should have definitely worked if you have included a using statement of the appropriate namespace; only issue then could be that the assembly is not referenced at all in your project.

Comment: check here for definition and example https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_7

Comment: Are you using Metro app or UWP ? Then, they are gone. Use List<T> instead.

Comment: @MrinalKamboj There is no System.Collections.dll.
The namespace "System.Collections" is defined in mscorlib.dll which should be included automatically as far as i know.

Comment: @Dr. Coconut, Great thanks my bad, was thinking of this being a separate dll as in many cases, haven't used it in a while

Comment: Forget `ArrayList`, why don't you use the `List<T>`, which is in `System.Collection.Generic` namespace and far better alternative than object based list

Comment: `System.Collections.ArrayList articles = new System.Collections.ArrayList();`

Comment: Yeah I agree with @MrinalKamboj. ArrayList is deprecated in favor of List<T> after .Net 2.0

Comment: @Rakitić The `ArrayList` keyword seems not to be present in `System.Collections` because it's not suggested when i hit Ctrl+Tab after typing `System.Collections`

Comment: I tried the `List<T>` and it works just fine. Thanks guys.

Comment: @PrinceGnakou your framework version? if it is v4.5 then `ArrayList` is not available. It's available till 4.0. See on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Rakitić  It is v4.5, so that is the reason? Didn't know about it.

Comment: yes :) So, it's better to use the Generic type.

Comment: @Rakitić Thanks a lot

Comment: @Rakitić the list problem is solved but i face the same problem with FileStream class. I was wondering if it was removed from the v4.5 too. If it was then what is the new version of FileStream?

Comment: @PrinceGnakou are you using the `System.IO;` namespace above?

Comment: @PrinceGnakou if you think the list problem is solved, then make sure you vote up and mark my answer solved :)

Comment: Yes, i'm using `System.IO` namespace but it's still not compiling.

Comment: I can't vote up since i don't have enough reputation, sorry  :(

Comment: @PrinceGnakou at least mark the answer as solved, so that further readers know it too :)

Comment: @Rakitić How do I do that since the answer is in comments?

Comment: @PrinceGnakou just see that i have already posted one answer below... don't know who downvoted that, though... :/ http://stackoverflow.com/a/38850068/6290553

Comment: I ended up correcting the problem by uninstalling and reinstalling my visual studio. Thanks All

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old post, but this might help someone else. As of 2018 and *Visual Studio 2017* you can use `ArrayList`.  They are apart of the `System.Collections` namespace.  All you have to do to use an `ArrayList` is import that namespace using the following:

```
Using System.Collections;
```

After you import this namespace you can use `ArrayList`, Stacks, Queues, and a few other goodies.

To declare an ArrayList you would use the following syntax

```
ArrayList variable = new ArrayList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<List Item> list = new List<List Item>();
```

You can use this code for .net version higher than 4.0.
* avoid spaces between List and Item inside <>
on both sides...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Framework 4.0 or higher Arraylist() is not available.You need to use the available Generic List

Comment: Finally they removed `ArrayList`. (I missed the memo). I am tired of seing "expert" `[c#]` programmers use `ArrayList`.

Answer (score -2):

```
System.Collections.ArrayList articles = new System.Collections.ArrayList();
```

This is correct syntax

Comment: The autocomplete feature doesn't even suggest `ArrayList` when i type `System.Collections.Arr` and then it  Ctrl + Tab